# Recommendation System for twitter-like web-application implementation in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is the algorithm I use to find the recommend system

To get the `current_user`'s followings: `current_user.followings`
To get the `current_user`'s followers : `current_user.followers`

- S = current_user.followings
- L = (s in S) UNION(s.followings)
- T = (l in L) UNION(l.followings)
- R = T-S

The algorithm is in [This Paper](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-730/paper3.pdf), page 5.

To recommend a user over the other from R, I evaluate each elements in R with the following formula: 
`score(person) = (occurences(person)/R.count) * (followers(person)/followees(person) * retweets(person)/tweets(person).count)`

The closer to 1 the score gets the more likely the user to be interested in that person.

I am having problem in the first part of the algorithm: name the counting of the occurrences of a person in R(occurrences(person)). I have the following code:

```
def candidates(user)  

  @following = user.following # the persons the user follows or S
  @follower = [] #defining an empty array to put L in

  @following.each  do |follow|
    @follower = @follower + follow.followers #populating the array
  end

  @followees = [] #defining an array to put T in

  @follower.each do |ff|
    @followees = @followees + ff.following #populating the array
  end

  @followees = @followees - @following  #getting rid of the persons that the user is already following so T - S which gives us R

@rezultat = []
@sugested = @followees & @followees #removing the duplicates

 @sugested.each do |gg| #for each user that he might want to follow
  nr = 0
  @followees.each do |ff|
    if (ff.email == gg.email) then nr = nr + 1 #find out how many times a user makes an appearance in the reunion of the intervals
    end
  end
  if(gg.following.count != 0) then
    score = ( nr/@followees.count() ) * ( gg.followers.count / gg.following.count) #calculating score without taking into consideration retweets yet 
  else score = 0
  end 
end

  end
end
```

Now I have to get the score. The problem I am facing with is counting the occurrences of the same object in R. The object are user model object which have the following fields:

- 1. Id
- 2. Name
- 3. Email

How I thought of counting them but I am not sure it works(plus it's not on my liking). Parse the whole array with the email of the current person I want to count the occurrences for and add 1 to a number every time I stumble across that email(since the email is unique). Any other ideas?

Furthermore how should I keep the relation Person-Score for easy sorting after score after I populate it so then I can get the Person Objects to display them :D ?.

Any tip or code is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little more ruby way:

```
@following = user.following

@follower = @following.collect { |following| following.followers }

@followees = @follower.collect { |follower| follower.following }

@followees = @followees - @following

@score = {}

@followees.uniq.map { |suggested| @score[suggested] = @followees.count(suggested)}

@score.select! { |user,count| count>0 && user.following.count>0 }

@score.each do |sguser,count| 
    @score[sguser] = 
     (count/sguser.followees.count) * 
     (sguser.followers.count / sguser.following.count)
end
```

As a result you will get hash @score { suggested_user: score_value } which you can sort as you wish.

And if your data is big enough you could move more to SQL land(JOIN, GROUP), reducing the size and the number of your arrays. Or maybe even do this right in the database not fetching any values at all to your app (AFAIK it's possible).

Comment: thank you very much, your code is very much ruby-like, unlike mine. I shall update my code :P !